# Shell: Get The Data From Remote Host And Excute Some Other Commands

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

I need to create a shell script to do this:

1. ssh to another remote host
2. use sqlplus on that host and spool command to get the data from oracle db into a file
3. transfer the file from that host to my host
4. excute another shell script to process the data file

I have finished the 4th step shell script. Now I have to do this 4 steps one by one. I want to create a script and do them all. Is that possible? How to transfer the data from one host to my host?

I think maybe the db file is not necessary.

Note: I have to ssh to another host to use sqlplus. It is the only one host which have the permission to access database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# steps 1 and 2
ssh remote_user@remote_host 'sqlplus db_user/db_pass@db @sql_script_that_spools'
# step 3
scp remote_user@remote_host:/path/to/spool_file local_file
# step 4
process local_file
```

Or

```
# steps 1, 2 and 3
ssh remote_user@remote_host 'sqlplus db_user/db_pass@db @sql_script_no_spool' > local_file
# step 4
process local_file
```

Or, all in one:

```
ssh remote_user@remote_host 'sqlplus db_user/db_pass@db @sql_script_no_spool' |
  process_stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Glenn pretty much summed it all up.

In order to make your life easier, you may want to also consider setting up passwordless ssh.  There is a slightly higher security risk associated with this, but in many cases the risk is negligible.

Here is a link to a good [tutorial](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152).  It is a debian based tutorial, but the commands given should work the same on most major linux distros.